# Interpretation of the singular integral for the definition of fractional Laplacian in classical case $s=1$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fractional-calculus

Fractional Laplacian is often defined via next principal value integral (assume dimension one for the simplicity)
$$(-\Delta)^su(x):=c_sP.V.\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{u(x)-u(y)}{|x-y|^{1+2s}}\, dy.$$
This improper integral makes sense when $s<1$, but how do we interpret this singular integral when $s=1$? It should correspond to classical local Laplacian, but the integral itself is not well-defined even as a principal value sense. Of course classical Laplacian is a local operator so definition via integral should not make sense as long as the kernel is not some singular distribution, but what can be said more about the interpretation of this improper integral? For me I do not see any immediate relation between $1/|x|^3$ and singular distributions (second order Dirac deltas). Also residue theorem pops up in my head, but I am not sure if there is any clear relation to it.

Thank you im advance.

Comment: I was missing the dependence on the constant $c_s$ in the limit of $s\rightarrow 1-$. I think it can be  understood that $c_s/|x|^{1+2s}\rightarrow \delta_0''$ in distribution, in the limit of $s\rightarrow 1-$, up to some constant.

Comment: This can be made sense of if one first view $f(x)=1/|x|^3$ as a distribution on $\mathbb R\setminus \{ 0\}$. There are various methods to extend this to a distribution on $\mathbb R$, discussed at length in Section 3.2 of Hormander I. Formula (3.2.17') relates these to $\delta''$, which is exactly what you want as $\delta''*u=\delta*u''=u''$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to interpret the singular integral for $s=1-\epsilon$ is by Fourier transformation, to check that it tends to $k^2 \hat{u}(k)$ when $\epsilon\downarrow 0$.

I will make use of the fact that the coefficient $c_s$, given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Laplacian), has the expansion
$$c_{1-\epsilon}=2\epsilon+{\cal O}(\epsilon^2).$$

First rewrite the right-hand-side in a way that I can remove the principal value (see [arXiv:1104.4345](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345), lemma 3.2)
$$F_\epsilon(x)\equiv c_{1-\epsilon}\operatorname{P.V.} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{u(x)-u(y)}{|x-y|^{3-2\epsilon}}\,dy$$
$$\qquad=\tfrac{1}{2}c_{1-\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{2u(x)-u(x+y)-u(x-y)}{|y|^{3-2\epsilon}}\,dy, \tag{*} \label{PV}$$
and Fourier transform to obtain
$$\hat{F}_\epsilon(k)\equiv\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx}F_\epsilon(x)\,dx=c_{1-\epsilon}\,\hat{u}(k)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1-\cos ky}{|y|^{3-2\epsilon}}\,dy=$$
$$\qquad=c_{1-\epsilon}\,k^{2-2\epsilon}\hat{u}(k)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1-\cos z}{|z|^{3-2\epsilon}}\,dz=c_{1-\epsilon}\,k^{2-2\epsilon}\hat{u}(k)  \; 2 \cos( \pi  \epsilon) \Gamma (2\epsilon-2)$$
$$\qquad\rightarrow k^2\hat{u}(k) \;\;\text{for}\;\;\epsilon\downarrow 0,$$
since
$  2 \cos( \pi  \epsilon) \Gamma (2\epsilon-2)=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}+{\cal O}(1)$.

Comment: Yes this makes sense, thank you. Although I wonder if we can make up an argument without Fourier transform (after all, in Fourier picture $s\rightarrow 1$ looks strightforward as pointwise convergence of Fourier multiplier $|\xi|^{2s}$ and dominated convergence of Schwartz?). But seeing the right hand side of your second equation now it looks doable in that way as well, by writing local Taylor expansion and showing nonlocal part goes zero. Thank you a lot.

Comment: This looks suspicious to me. For $s=1-\epsilon\not=1$, the fractional Laplacian is of course multiplication by $|k|^{2s}$ on the Fourier side, not multiplication by $c_s |k|^2$, as your formulae state, so this cannot be right if the OP's representation of $(-\Delta)^s$ is correct. (Put differently, we don't need any calculation to verify that the limit comes out right, as obviously $\widehat{(-\Delta)^s u}=|k|^{2s}\widehat{u}\to k^2\widehat{u}$.)

Comment: The problem is that you ignore the PV regularization and replace with another one in your formula for $F_{\epsilon}$, which doesn't give the same result. (Your first formula for $F_{\epsilon}$, which you copied from the OP, but with the PV dropped, does not make rigorous sense.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling -- for general $s$ I find $\hat{F}_s(k)=c_s\hat{u}(k)|k|^{2s}$ times the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty(1-\cos z)|z|^{-1-2s}\,dz$, which equals $1/c_s$ by definition of $c_s$, so indeed $\hat{F}_s(k)=\hat{u}(k)|k|^{2s}$.

Comment: concerning the principal value: the numerator $2u(x)-u(x+y)-u(x-y)$ vanishes quadratically for small $y$, so the singularity is integrable and I don't need the principal value; I have added a reference for this transformation.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: I understand that. The question is whether the PV regularization and your procedure give the same result.

Comment: @ChristianRemling -- is the question about equation (\ref{PV}) ? --- that is lemma (3.2) from the cited paper, it follows directly from a change of variables ($y\mapsto x\pm z$).

Answer (score 1):

Just for sake of sharing, I add my elementary idea: For any $f\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ (for more general function it is a common practice to define via distribution $\langle (-\Delta)^sf,g\rangle:=\langle f,(-\Delta)^s g\rangle$ for all $g\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with some given conditions on $f$), we have

$$
\begin{align*}
&(-\Delta)^sf(0)\\
&=c(s)P.V.\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(0)-f(x)}{|x|^{1+2s}}\,dx\\
&=c(s)P.V.\int_{B_\epsilon(0)}\frac{f(0)-f(x)}{|x|^{1+2s}}\,dx\\
&+c(s)\int_{B_\epsilon^c(0)}\frac{f(0)-f(x)}{|x|^{1+2s}}\,dx\\
&=c(s)P.V.\int_{B_\epsilon(0)}-f'(0)\textrm{sign}(x)|x|^{-2s}-\frac{f''(0)}{2}|x|^{1-2s}+O(|x|^{2-2s})\,dx+c(s)C_{\epsilon,f}O(1)\\
&=-f''(0)\frac{c(s)\epsilon^{2-2s}}{2-2s}+c(s)O(\epsilon^{4-2s})+c(s)C_{\epsilon,f}O(1)\\
&\xrightarrow{s\rightarrow 1} -f''(0),
\end{align*}
$$
because $c(s)$ has order one zero at $s=1$, i.e. $c(s)\sim 2(1-s)$, and the second and third term just vanishs in the limit of $s\rightarrow 1-$. I did not verify that $\lim_{s\rightarrow 1-}\frac{c(s)\epsilon^{2-2s}}{2-2s}=1$ with the precise definition of $c(s)$, but I guess it should be true if $c_s$ is choosen properly. So we just have the classical Laplacian as we hoped.

EDIT: For the completeness I add the interpretation for $(-\Delta)^{s}\xrightarrow{s\rightarrow 0+}Id$ in the limit $s\rightarrow 0+$ as well. In this case all terms vanish except the one multiplied with $f(0)$.

$$
\begin{align*}
&(-\Delta)^sf(0)=c(s)P.V.\int_{B_\epsilon(0)}\frac{f(0)-f(x)}{|x|^{1+2s}}\,dx\\
&+c(s)\int_{B_\epsilon^c(0)}\frac{f(0)-f(x)}{|x|^{1+2s}}\,dx\\
&=c(s)C_{\epsilon,f}O(1)+f(0)\frac{c(s)\epsilon^{-2s}}{2s}\\
&\xrightarrow{s\rightarrow 0+}f(0),
\end{align*}
$$
because $c(s)\sim 2s$ near $s\sim 0$. Note that we have used $\int_{B_\epsilon^c(0)}\frac{f(x)}{|x|^{1+2s}}=C_{\epsilon,f}O(1)$.